# Sum of an odd recursive sequence

Tags: sequences-and-series, summation, recursion, sequence-of-function

Let

$a_0 = 1$

$a_1 = 1 - \frac{e}{2}$

$a_n = \frac{e}{2^n} - \frac{1 - a_{n-1}}{n - 1}$ for $n > 1$.

Find $\sum_{r=0}^{\infty}a_r$.

Comment: The recurrence formula doesn't agree with the initial condition at $n=1$. As given, perhaps the following may help: let $b_n=1-a_n$, then $b_0=0$, $b_1=\frac{e}{2}$, $b_n=1-\frac{e}{2^n}+\frac{b_{n-1}}{n-1}$ for $n\ge 1$.

Comment: @AlexanderBurstein Correct, that was my mistake, I fixed it. It was meant to be $n > 1$ as the first two members are given. I've tried solving it mant ways, but can't come up with anything new... Can't succeed with your idea neither.

Comment: Try using exponential generating functions. Alternatively, multiply my equation in the comment through by $n!$.

Comment: Correction: multiply through by $(n-1)!$.

Comment: I shared the problem with a friend of mine and he stated the series was divergent indeed, which I also had suspicions of... I myself haven't had the time to work on it ever since but if I don't forget, I'll take another look. Thanks!